# Multiple Card Carousels on One Page with Bootstrap 5

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

After trying for at least 30 minutes, I cannot completely visually recreate my problem on Stackoverflow, as more errors arise. But basically, I want to be able to have multiple Bootstrap 5 Card Carousels on one page, and have the functionality to move it along using the indicators. When using `Alert(pid)`, it presents the correct id... however, it doesn't move the carousel along.

1. Locally there are three cards per row
2. Locally the indicators are visible

Still, thought I'd add the code for context.

```js
var carouselWidth = $(".carousel-inner")[0].scrollWidth;
var cardWidth = $(".carousel-item").width();
var scrollPosition = 0;

$('.carousel-control-next').on('click', function() {
  var pid = $(this).parent().attr('id');
  if (scrollPosition < carouselWidth - cardWidth * 4) {
    scrollPosition += cardWidth;
    $('#' + pid + '.carousel-inner').animate({
      scrollRight: scrollPosition
    }, 600);
  }
  //alert(pid);
});

$('.carousel-control-prev').on('click', function() {
  var pid = $(this).parent().attr('id');
  if (scrollPosition > 0) {
    scrollPosition -= cardWidth;
    $('#' + pid + ' .carousel-inner').animate({
      scrollLeft: scrollPosition
    }, 600);
  }
  // alert('prev');
});
```

```css
.carousel {
    position: relative;
}
.carousel-control-next, .carousel-control-prev {
    position: absolute !important;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 15%;
    padding: 0;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    background: 0 0;
    border: 0;
    opacity: .5;
    transition: opacity .15s ease;
}
.carousel-control-next-icon, .carousel-control-prev-icon {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 2rem;
    height: 2rem;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50%;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}

.carousel-control-prev, .carousel-control-next {
    background-color: #e1e1e1;
    width: 6vh;
    height: 6vh;
    border-radius: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.carousel-control-prev {
    left: 0;
}
.carousel-control-next {
    right: 0;
}
.carousel-control-prev-icon {
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 16 16' fill='%23fff'%3e%3cpath d='M11.354 1.646a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .708L5.707 8l5.647 5.646a.5.5 0 0 1-.708.708l-6-6a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.708l6-6a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0z'/%3e%3c/svg%3e")
}

.carousel-control-next-icon {
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 16 16' fill='%23fff'%3e%3cpath d='M4.646 1.646a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0l6 6a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .708l-6 6a.5.5 0 0 1-.708-.708L10.293 8 4.646 2.354a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.708z'/%3e%3c/svg%3e")
}


.carousel-inner {
  padding: 1em;
}

.card {
  margin: 0 0.5em;
  box-shadow: 2px 6px 8px 0 rgba(22, 22, 26, 0.18);
  border: none;
}

.carousel-control-prev,
.carousel-control-next {
  background-color: #e1e1e1;
  width: 6vh;
  height: 6vh;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .carousel-item {
    margin-right: 0;
    flex: 0 0 33.333333%;
    display: block !important;
  }
  .carousel-inner {
    display: flex;
  }
}

.card .img-wrapper {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 13em;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.card img {
  max-height: 100%;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .card .img-wrapper {
    height: 17em;
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.0.0-beta2/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha512-43iShtbiyImxjjU4a9rhXBy7eKtIsrpll8xKhe1ghKqh5NyfME8phZs5JRFZpRBe1si44WM3tNmnqMym7JRmDQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.0.0-beta2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-aqT9YD5gLuLBr6ipQAS+72o5yHKzgZbGxEh6iY8lW/r6gG14e2kBTAJb8XrxzZrMOgSmDqtLaF76T0Z6YY2IHg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />


<!-- Carousel 1 -->

<section class="pt-5 pb-5">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 col-12">
        <h2 class="h3">TV &amp; Movie Cast Members</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="carouselExampleControls1" class="carousel" data-bs-ride="carousel">
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body text-center">
              <h3 class="card-title h4"><a class="stretched-link" href="#">X</a></h3>
              <span class=" mt-4 btn btn-primary">See The List</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body text-center">
              <h3 class="card-title h4"><a class="stretched-link" href="#">XX</a></h3>
              <span class=" mt-4 btn btn-primary">See The List</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body text-center">
              <h3 class="card-title h4"><a class="stretched-link" href="#">XXX</a></h3>
              <span class=" mt-4 btn btn-primary">See The List</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body text-center">
              <h3 class="card-title h4"><a class="stretched-link" href="#">XXXX</a></h3>
              <span class=" mt-4 btn btn-primary">See The List</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
    </button>
      <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
    </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<!-- Carousel 2 -->
<section class="pt-5 pb-5">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 col-12">
        <h2 class="h3">TV &amp; Movie Cast Members</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="carouselExampleControls2" class="carousel" data-bs-ride="carousel">
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body text-center">
              <h3 class="card-title h4"><a class="stretched-link" href="#">X</a></h3>
              <span class=" mt-4 btn btn-primary">See The List</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body text-center">
              <h3 class="card-title h4"><a class="stretched-link" href="#">XX</a></h3>
              <span class=" mt-4 btn btn-primary">See The List</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body text-center">
              <h3 class="card-title h4"><a class="stretched-link" href="#">XXX</a></h3>
              <span class=" mt-4 btn btn-primary">See The List</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body text-center">
              <h3 class="card-title h4"><a class="stretched-link" href="#">XXXX</a></h3>
              <span class=" mt-4 btn btn-primary">See The List</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
    </button>
      <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
    </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

you just nee to tweak the HTML, if you look in each carousels individual HTML you will see

```
data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls"
```

change that to match the of the carousel that it resides within, e.g.

```
data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls1"
```

```js
var carouselWidth = $(".carousel-inner")[0].scrollWidth;
var cardWidth = $(".carousel-item").width();
var scrollPosition = 0;

$('.carousel-control-next').on('click', function() {
  var pid = $(this).parent().attr('id');
  if (scrollPosition < carouselWidth - cardWidth * 4) {
    scrollPosition += cardWidth;
    $('#' + pid + '.carousel-inner').animate({
      scrollRight: scrollPosition
    }, 600);
  }
  console.log(pid);
});

$('.carousel-control-prev').on('click', function() {
  var pid = $(this).parent().attr('id');
  if (scrollPosition > 0) {
    scrollPosition -= cardWidth;
    $('#' + pid + ' .carousel-inner').animate({
      scrollLeft: scrollPosition
    }, 600);
  }
  console.log(pid);
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


  <!-- jQuery -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <!-- CSS -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>

<body>


  <!-- Carousel 1 -->

  <section class="pt-5 pb-5">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-12">
          <h2 class="h3">TV &amp; Movie Cast Members</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="carouselExampleControls1" class="carousel" data-bs-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="carousel-item active">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-body text-center">
                <h3 class="card-title h4"><a class="stretched-link" href="#">X</a></h3>
                <span class=" mt-4 btn btn-primary">See The List</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-body text-center">
                <h3 class="card-title h4"><a class="stretched-link" href="#">XX</a></h3>
                <span class=" mt-4 btn btn-primary">See The List</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-body text-center">
                <h3 class="card-title h4"><a class="stretched-link" href="#">XXX</a></h3>
                <span class=" mt-4 btn btn-primary">See The List</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-body text-center">
                <h3 class="card-title h4"><a class="stretched-link" href="#">XXXX</a></h3>
                <span class=" mt-4 btn btn-primary">See The List</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls1" data-bs-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
      </button>
        <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls1" data-bs-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
      </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <!-- Carousel 2 -->
  <section class="pt-5 pb-5">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-12">
          <h2 class="h3">TV &amp; Movie Cast Members</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="carouselExampleControls2" class="carousel" data-bs-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="carousel-item active">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-body text-center">
                <h3 class="card-title h4"><a class="stretched-link" href="#">X</a></h3>
                <span class=" mt-4 btn btn-primary">See The List</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-body text-center">
                <h3 class="card-title h4"><a class="stretched-link" href="#">XX</a></h3>
                <span class=" mt-4 btn btn-primary">See The List</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-body text-center">
                <h3 class="card-title h4"><a class="stretched-link" href="#">XXX</a></h3>
                <span class=" mt-4 btn btn-primary">See The List</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-body text-center">
                <h3 class="card-title h4"><a class="stretched-link" href="#">XXXX</a></h3>
                <span class=" 

mt-4 btn btn-primary">See The List</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls2" data-bs-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
      </button>
        <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls2" data-bs-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
      </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

I hope this helps